# postgres select specific rows or select all rows depending on values within an array

Tags: postgresql

I have this table as an example:

[image]

I would like a query to return select tools based upon the permission, here is a small python code of what I would like to achieve with the query:

```
user_permissions = ['admin', 'user-perm1']
if any(perm in ['admin', 'super-user'] for perm in user_permissions):
  #return all tools
else:
  #select all tools where column perm in user_permissions
```

is there a single query that can do this?

Comment: From docs [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16), something like: `select all tools where case when <user> = ANY(ARRAY['admin', 'super-user']) perm is not null else perm =  ANY(ARRAY['admin', 'user-perm1']) end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use CASE:

```
SELECT * FROM tools
WHERE CASE WHEN <perm_parameter> IN ('admin', 'super-user') THEN TRUE ELSE 
tools.perm=<perm_parameter> END;
```

Greetings, Alejandro

Comment: thank you! This help set me in the right direction, the query :  `SELECT * FROM test
WHERE CASE WHEN array['admin','user-perm1'] && array['admin', 'super-user'] THEN TRUE 
ELSE test.perm in ('admin', 'user-perm1') END;` worked!